# How to Make a link to download PDF file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have created a link that download the PDF file When click on the Link.

Here is my .cshtml:

```
<h1>Hello Shuainan</h1>
<a href="/Account/PdfDownload">download</a>


<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download('test.pdf')" />

<script>
    function download(file) {
        window.location = file;
    }
</script>
```

and the download function is :

```
public void PdfDownload(string path, string fileName)
{
      var myPDF = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\myPDF.pdf");

      Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

      Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testPDF.pdf");
      Response.Body.Write(myPDF, 0, 2048);
}
```

But then I can't load the PDF file when the download is finished.

Comment: Don't write directly to the response. Return a FileResult.

Comment: You may try this . return File(filename, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(filename));

Comment: return File(myPDF, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(myPDF)); @riteshmeher .I dont know why the server doesnt exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Action method that return file action result as

```
public ActionResult PdfDownload()
    {
        string TempFilePath = @"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\myPDF.pdf";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath))
        {
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = "testPDF.pdf",
                Inline = false,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(TempFilePath, "application/pdf");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And Then in view use as:

```
    <h1>Hello Shuainan</h1>
<a href="/Account/PdfDownload">download</a>
```

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\myPDF.pdf      \\******     But aturelly I have this file  C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\myPDF.pdf

Comment: ok, I think you need to put file in the application directory and then use Server.MapPath(), Suppose you put file in pdffiles/myPDF.pdf then Code will be string TempFilePath = Server.MapPath("/pdffiles/myPDF.pdf");

Comment: string TempFilePath = Server.MapPath("/pdffiles/myPDF.pdf");   it shows error that the name "server" doesnt exist in current context. Microsoft.AspNet.Server.MapPath? right? I dont know its the problem with .net5?

Comment: import package using System.Web;. If you are in action method then Server will be in scope

Comment: If you want know more about Server.MapPath follow the link http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/CSharp/Server_MapPath(%E2%80%9C_%E2%80%9D),-Server_MapPath(%E2%80%9C~%E2%80%9D),-Server_MapPath(@%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9D),-Server_MapPath(%E2%80%9C-%E2%80%9D)_-What-is-the-difference/20332

Comment: atually I import the package using System.Web; Still not work :(, the name "server" only show quick action with AspNet.Server and Sqlserver.Server..

Comment: [HttpGet][AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult PdfDownload()
 {
 string TempFilePath = Server.MapPath("/pdffiles/myPDF.pdf");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath))
 {
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
 {
FileName = "testPDF.pdf",
Inline = false,
                };
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
return File(TempFilePath, "application/pdf");
}
else
{
return null;
 }
}

Comment: ok, try to use this one System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(). So,  string TempFilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/pdffiles/myPDF.pdf");

Comment: the web.Hosting is not exist too. why :(

Comment: you can check for previous as HttpContext.Server.MapPath() Or You have to show all controller code in  which you have created action method

Comment: // GET: api/Users
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetAll(string email)
        {
            var user = ShelfxClient.XManager.FindCustomerByEmail(email);
            if (user != null) return "OK - " + user.first_name;
            else return "KO";
        }

        // POST: api/Sms
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post(List<string> numbers, string message)
        {
            var s = Common.Phone.SmsManager.SendMessage(numbers, message);
            return s;
        }

Comment: It's not enough for judging. I want the initial line of code like importing the package section and inheriting the Controller etc.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using NU.Mini.Common.ThirdPartyApis;
using System.Web;

Comment: namespace NU.Mini.WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : MiniNUApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        
        public ActionResult PdfDownload()
        {
string TempFilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/pdffiles/myPDF.pdf");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath))
{
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
FileName = "testPDF.pdf",
Inline = false,
};
 Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                return File(TempFilePath, "application/pdf");
}
else
return null;
}
}

Comment: thats all :)    ~~

Comment: I think you are using some Third party api controller. You need to learn more about that.

Comment: :) Get it !TY bro!